# How to Fill the div Via JQuery with an Transitional Approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I am trying to develop an app that shows an empty dustbin.

```css
.content {
  min-height: auto;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

section {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.trash {
  background: rgba(64,231,173,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(1%, rgba(64,231,173,1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(68,237,168,1)), color-stop(69%, rgba(77,248,157,1)), color-stop(97%, rgba(82,255,151,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40e7ad', endColorstr='#52ff97', GradientType=1 );
  width: 66px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

.trash span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  background: rgba(64,231,173,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(1%, rgba(64,231,173,1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(68,237,168,1)), color-stop(69%, rgba(77,248,157,1)), color-stop(97%, rgba(82,255,151,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40e7ad', endColorstr='#52ff97', GradientType=1 );
  top: -19px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
 
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 250ms;
  transform-origin: 19% 100%;
}

.trash span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 27px;
  height: 7px;
  background: rgba(64,231,173,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(1%, rgba(64,231,173,1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(68,237,168,1)), color-stop(69%, rgba(77,248,157,1)), color-stop(97%, rgba(82,255,151,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(64,231,173,1) 1%, rgba(68,237,168,1) 24%, rgba(77,248,157,1) 69%, rgba(82,255,151,1) 97%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40e7ad', endColorstr='#52ff97', GradientType=1 );
  top: -10px;
 
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 250ms;
  transform-origin: 19% 100%;
  left: 27px;
}

.trash i {
  position:relative;
  width: 58px;
  height:70px;
  background:#fff;
  display:block;
  margin:5px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.trash:hover span {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: transform 250ms;
}
```

```html
<ion-card class="indicatorArea">
  <ion-card-header class="content">
    <section>
      <span class="trash">
        <span></span>
        <i></i>
      </span>
    </section>
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content class="main">
    Some Data Here
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to fill the bin till the end and the cap of the bin gets open.

Example: The bin is empty at 0% and is green in color gradient. What happens is now when I set 30 as the value of percentage through JQuery. Now the bin div should be filled up to 30% of its current status.

As the bin full to 100% the bin cap will be open and the status of the bin will be 100%

However, I am facing issues while implementing it. What might be a good approach to achieve it? Also whenever the bin is filling with color it should be in transition.

Comment: your example is not working

Comment: Please paste your code here...

Comment: I've updated the Post @Max

Comment: I've updated the Post @PPL

Comment: you should post your js code instead of css code

Comment: I am not using any JS code currently this is all the code i have done but i am trying to approach through JS. Even if solution is through pure css3 then also its ok i can manipulate it accordingly though JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var fill = 0;
$("#button").on("click", function() {
  var value = parseInt($("#text").val());
  if(!isNaN(value)){
  if(value > 100 || value < 0)
  {
  alert("Please enter number between 0-100");
  return;
  }
  total = value;
  $(".trash").attr("data-fill", total);
  $(".filled").css({
    "height": total + "%"
  });
  $("#text").val("");
  if (total >= 100) {
    $(".trash span").addClass("open");
    $(".filled").css({
      "height": 100 + "%"
    });
  } else {
    $(".trash span").removeClass("open");
  }
  if(total > 0){
  var srColor= 100 - total;
  $("span.trash").css({
      "background": "linear-gradient(to top, red "+total+"%, rgba(68, 237,  168, 1) "+srColor+"%)"
    });
   }else{
   $("span.trash").css({
      "background": ""
    });
   }
 }else{
 alert("Please enter correct number!!");
 }
})
```

```css
.content {
  min-height: auto;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.indicatorArea {
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.trash i.filled {
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  /* background: #dce7eb; */
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.trash {
  background: rgba(64, 231, 173, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(1%, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1)), color-stop(69%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1)), color-stop(97%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40e7ad', endColorstr='#52ff97', GradientType=1);
  width: 66px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

.trash:after {
  content: 'Your iBin Status 'attr(data-fill)'%';
  position: absolute;
  left: -23px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
}

.trash span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  background: rgba(64, 231, 173, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(1%, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1)), color-stop(69%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1)), color-stop(97%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40e7ad', endColorstr='#52ff97', GradientType=1);
  top: -19px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 250ms;
  transform-origin: 19% 100%;
}

.trash span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 27px;
  height: 7px;
  background: rgba(64, 231, 173, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(1%, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1)), color-stop(69%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1)), color-stop(97%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40e7ad', endColorstr='#52ff97', GradientType=1);
  top: -10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 250ms;
  transform-origin: 19% 100%;
  left: 27px;
}

.trash i {
  position: relative;
  width: 58px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.trash span.open {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: transform 250ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter value here...">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Fill">
<ion-card class="indicatorArea">
  <ion-card-header class="content">
    <section>
      <span class="trash" data-fill="0">
        <span></span>
      <i><i class="filled"></i></i>
      </span>
    </section>
  </ion-card-header>
</ion-card>
```

Please check this code. Let me know if I am missing something.

### Update

```js
var fill = 0;
$("#button").on("click", function() {
  var value = parseInt($("#text").val());
  if(!isNaN(value)){
  if(value > 100 || value < 0)
  {
  alert("Please enter number between 0-100");
  return;
  }
  total = value;
  $(".trash").attr("data-fill", total);
  $(".filled").css({
    "height": total + "%"
  });
  $("#text").val("");
  if (total >= 100) {
    $(".trash span").addClass("open");
    $(".filled").css({
      "height": 100 + "%"
    });
  } else {
    $(".trash span").removeClass("open");
  }
  if(total > 0){
  var srColor= 100 - total;
  $("span.trash").css({
      "background": "red"
    });
   }else{
   $("span.trash").css({
      "background": "rgba(64, 231, 173, 1)"
    });
   }
 }else{
 alert("Please enter correct number!!");
 }
})
```

```css
.content {
  min-height: auto;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.indicatorArea {
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.trash i.filled {
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  /* background: #dce7eb; */
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.trash {
  background: rgba(64, 231, 173, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(1%, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1)), color-stop(69%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1)), color-stop(97%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40e7ad', endColorstr='#52ff97', GradientType=1);
  width: 66px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

.trash:after {
  content: 'Your iBin Status 'attr(data-fill)'%';
  position: absolute;
  left: -23px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
}

.trash span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  background: rgba(64, 231, 173, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(1%, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1)), color-stop(69%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1)), color-stop(97%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40e7ad', endColorstr='#52ff97', GradientType=1);
  top: -19px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 250ms;
  transform-origin: 19% 100%;
}

.trash span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 27px;
  height: 7px;
  background: rgba(64, 231, 173, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(1%, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1)), color-stop(69%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1)), color-stop(97%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(64, 231, 173, 1) 1%, rgba(68, 237, 168, 1) 24%, rgba(77, 248, 157, 1) 69%, rgba(82, 255, 151, 1) 97%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40e7ad', endColorstr='#52ff97', GradientType=1);
  top: -10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 250ms;
  transform-origin: 19% 100%;
  left: 27px;
}

.trash i {
  position: relative;
  width: 58px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.trash span.open {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: transform 250ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter value here...">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Fill">
<ion-card class="indicatorArea">
  <ion-card-header class="content">
    <section>
      <span class="trash" data-fill="0">
        <span></span>
      <i><i class="filled"></i></i>
      </span>
    </section>
  </ion-card-header>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: The code works brilliant. Is there any way to also change the color accordingly of the trash from green to red accordingly? I mean the color which i am specifying in filling the thrash the outside also should be able to adapt the same color. Is there a possible way or any trick?

Comment: there is an error in your code though see whatever number i enter it should not get addition or subtraction. The bin will reset and fill color according to number entered your current code does addition and subtraction. Please Update your code so i can mark it :)

Comment: I have edited my code for 2nd comment. Can you please explain your first comment in detail? @Developer

Comment: my first comment means like initially my bin is green in color now the color inside the bin is red so i want the entire bin to adapt the color red or any other color i provide inside the bin

Comment: I have again edited my code. See its look good then turning the entire bin red? Your thoughts? @Developer

Comment: Also please mark the answer approved if it helped. :) Thanks @Developer

Comment: after entering 45% and above the linear gradient doesn't apply

Comment: It's working fine here. Please check again. @Developer

Comment: Please Enter 10% it gives gradient effect then enter 50% or above you'll see the difference

Comment: Ohh I see. Because there is no space left for the gradient effect. That's the reason behind it. @Developer

Comment: Can you please give me a resolved solution code over it?

Comment: Change whole bin border to red? As you were saying before. @Developer

Comment: Ok i'll figure out something over it :)